# No route match in search box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I implemented the search box in ruby on rails according to this [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form?autoplay=true) like this

```
<% form_tag ticket_path, :method =>  'get' do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=>nil %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since your problem is with routes, It is necessary to see your routes file and controller code related to your search form in order to find the cause.

Comment: Post what error you are getting, controller code, routes and additional information

Answer (score 0):

Use `tickets_path` instead of `ticket_path`. First points to `index` action. The second is for `show` action and require parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Alex Kojin is correct. You just made a spelling mistake following the tutorial.

```
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

notice plural in route:

```
projects_path
```